# Qual é a diferença das continuações do Scheme para as de outras linguagens?

Tags: programação-funcional

Já ouvi dizer que o Scheme possui "continuações de primeira classe", enquanto outros Lisps (e outras linguagens) não têm. Eu pesquisei sobre isso, mas o material que encontrei não era específico.

O que eu entendi é que continuações são como as funções de callback no Node.js, mas com um propósito diferente. Por exemplo, sem continuação:

```lisp
(define (ao-quadrado x)
  (* x x))
```

E com continuação:

```lisp
(define (ao-quadrado x cont)
  (cont (* x x)))
```

Existe mais alguma diferença? Eu perdi algo no caminho?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As funções callback do nodejs não um caso particular de continuações. "Continuação" é um termo mais genérico que isso.

Traduzindo da [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation):

> Uma continuação é uma representação **abstrata** do estado do fluxo de execução de um programa. Uma continuação reifica o controle de fluxo implícito em uma função explícita

Por exemplo, suponha que eu esteja fazendo a seguinte conta:

```
(define (conta)
  (* (+ 1 2) 4))
```

Existe uma ordem implícita do controle de fluxo quando eu executo essas operações. Eu pósso explicitá-la convertendo o programa pra single assignment form:

```
a <- 1 + 2
b <- a * 4
```

Continuações são uma maneira de representar essa ordem de execução implícita. Dado um ponto no código, a continuação desse ponto é uma função que representa o que vai acontecer no futuro. Por exemplo, a continuação do ponto da operação de soma na terceira linha é uma função `(lambda (a) (a * 4))`

Uma coisa que podemos fazer com continuações é escrever nosso programa de forma que as continuações aparecem explicitamente. Isso se chama **Continuation Passing Style** e é o que as pessoas fazem no Nodejs. No nosso exemplo, isso seria usar operações como +-cps e *-cps ao invés de + e * que retornam valores:

```
(define (conta-cps cont)
  (+-cps 1 2 (lambda (a)
    (*-cps a 4 cont)))
```

Programar assim tem alguns benefícios. Por exemplo, com continuações você pode "pausar" a execução do código. Basta pegar a continuação e salvar ela em alguma estrutura de dados e chamar ele de volta depois. Continuações também permitem que você implemente alguns mecanismos de controle você mesmo, como "return" , "try-catch" e iteradores.

O problema é que é um saco converter todas as suas funções para CPS na mão. É aqui que entram as continuaçÕes de primeira classe, usando o call-with-current-continuation (call/cc) você pode escrever seu código sem continuações mas você tem acesso às continuações como se você tivesse escrito o código em CPS.

Não vou dar exemplos de call/cc porque eu acho que o código fica muito complicado. Na prática você pode usar outras ferramentas menos poderosas que te dão benf;icios similares (poder pausar e reiniciar a execução do programa, etc). Por exemplo, em Scheme existem continuaçÕes delimitadas, em Python você tem geradores e em Lua você tem corotinas.

Answer (score 5):

As continuações em Scheme são como que closures aumentadas que capturam a pilha de retorno, o ambiente e o ponto de execução actual.  Noutras linguagens, como JavaScript, continuações são "meras" funções ou closures que capturam o ambiente à volta.

Desta forma, é possível, por exemplo, pegar numa função de mapeamento, que tipicamente chama uma função para cada elemento, e fazer um iterador, que é chamado para retornar o elemento seguinte:

```
(define (my-hash-iterator a-hash)
  (let ((return-values #f)
        (read-value #f))
    (lambda ()
      (let/cc iteration
        (set! return-values iteration)
        (if read-value
            (read-value)
            (begin
              (hash-table-for-each a-hash
                                   (lambda (key value)
                                     (let/cc cont
                                       (set! read-value cont)
                                       (return-values #t key value))))
              (set! read-value #f)    ; iterador volta ao início se chamado novamente
              (return-values #f #f #f)))))))
```

A ideia é entrar na função dada à `hash-table-for-each` e apanhar uma continuação lá dentro, `(set! read-value cont)`, que quando invocada, a fará retornar para `hash-table-for-each`.  A continuação de fora é para retornar cada um dos valores à vez.